# XSLT 2, Mutiple grouping by attributes and elements

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I can't seem to manage grouping couple based on their MaritalStatus.
I've manage to group all the person that are in a relationship  ('DeFacto', 'Married') but can't figuring out how to group them in different households.

Basically if two persons make a couple they will create a Household. The household name will belong to the first person surname in the household, the NumberOfAdults will be hardcoded to '2' and the NumberOfDependants will be summed.

The couple is linked based on the Party.Identifier and the Party.MaritalStatus.RelatedEntityRef

What i have(simplified):

```
<PartySegment>
<Party Type="Guarantor" PrimaryApplicant="No">
    <Identifier>b8b0f908b08e</Identifier>
    <Person Sex="Female" FirstHomeBuyer="No" CustomerOfLender="No">
        <PersonName>
            <NameTitle Value="Lady"/>
            <FirstName>Clemansa</FirstName>
            <Surname>Sanchez</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <MaritalStatus Status="DeFacto">
            <RelatedEntityRef>ea384b0bf3f5</RelatedEntityRef>
        </MaritalStatus>
        <NumberOfDependents>1</NumberOfDependents>
    </Person>
</Party>
<Party Type="Applicant" PrimaryApplicant="Yes" ExistingCustomerID="1231">
    <Identifier>bd8c65a3ad80</Identifier>
    <Person Sex="Female" FirstHomeBuyer="Yes" CustomerOfLender="Yes">
        <PersonName>
            <NameTitle Value="Mrs"/>
            <FirstName>Cheryl</FirstName>
            <Surname>Bonkers</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <MaritalStatus Status="Married">
            <RelatedEntityRef>ee84dc9e38ec</RelatedEntityRef>
        </MaritalStatus>
        <NumberOfDependents>2</NumberOfDependents>
    </Person>
</Party>
<Party Type="Guarantor" PrimaryApplicant="No">
    <Identifier>ea384b0bf3f5</Identifier>
    <Person Sex="Male" FirstHomeBuyer="No" CustomerOfLender="No">
        <PersonName>
            <NameTitle Value="Mr"/>
            <FirstName>Greg</FirstName>
            <OtherName>Morty</OtherName>
            <Surname>Sanchez</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <MaritalStatus Status="DeFacto">
            <RelatedEntityRef>b8b0f908b08e</RelatedEntityRef>
        </MaritalStatus>
        <NumberOfDependents>0</NumberOfDependents>
    </Person>
</Party>
<Party Type="Applicant" PrimaryApplicant="No">
    <Identifier>ee84dc9e38ec</Identifier>
    <Person Sex="Male" FirstHomeBuyer="No" CustomerOfLender="No">
        <PersonName>
            <NameTitle Value="Mr"/>
            <FirstName>Mark</FirstName>
            <Surname>Bonkers</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <MaritalStatus Status="Married">
            <RelatedEntityRef>bd8c65a3ad80</RelatedEntityRef>
        </MaritalStatus>
        <NumberOfDependents>0</NumberOfDependents>
    </Person>
</Party>
</PartySegment>
```

The desire output:

```
<Household UniqueID="b8b0f908b08e-Household"
                Name="Sanchez Household"
                NumberOfAdults="2"
                NumberOfDependants="1"/>

<Household UniqueID="bd8c65a3ad80-Household"
                Name="Bonkers Household"
                NumberOfAdults="2"
                NumberOfDependants="2"/>
```

What i have so far(simplified): This is working for one couple because is not taking in consideration the MaritalStatus.RelatedEntityRef information

```
<xsl:template match="PartySegment" mode="Household_Couple">

    <xsl:for-each-group select="Party[Person/MaritalStatus/@Status = ('DeFacto', 'Married')]" group-by="Person/MaritalStatus/@Status = ('DeFacto', 'Married')">
        <xsl:variable name="owner_id" select="Identifier"/>

        <Household UniqueID="{concat(Identifier, '-Household')}" 
            Name="{normalize-space(concat(Person/PersonName/Surname, ' Household'))}"
            NumberOfAdults="{'2'}"
            NumberOfDependants="{if(Person/Dependent) then count(current-group()/Person/Dependent) else if(Person/NumberOfDependents) then sum(current-group()/Person/NumberOfDependents) else '0'}">

            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/Person/Dependent"/>

        </Household>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am  not sure it is a grouping task, seems rather you want to follow the cross-reference with a key. Is there some way to distinguish `Party` elements, would it suffice to process all `Party[@Type = 'Guarantor' and Person/MaritalStatus/@Status = ('DeFacto', 'Married')]` and then simply search the referenced other `Party` with a `<xsl:key name="ref" match="Party" use="Identifier">` and `key('ref', MaritalStatus/RelatedEntityRef)`?

Comment: The Party elements can be only Applicants or Guarantors. Some Partys are in a relationship  (DeFacto, Married) and share expenses (and are belonging to a single household) and some are single, divorced etc with their expenses and this creates their own household.
I've implemented all the information for a person that creates a Household for one person but not for multiple couples (is working for one couple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can move to XSLT 3.0 then I think a composite grouping key `sort((Identifier, key('ref', Person/MaritalStatus/RelatedEntityRef)/Identifier))` of the sort of the two related identifiers can solve this:

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="Party" use="Identifier"/>

<xsl:template match="PartySegment">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Party[Person/MaritalStatus/@Status = ('DeFacto', 'Married')]" 
        composite="yes" 
        group-by="sort((Identifier, key('ref', Person/MaritalStatus/RelatedEntityRef)/Identifier))">
        <Household UniqueID="{concat(Identifier, '-Household')}" 
            Name="{normalize-space(concat(Person/PersonName/Surname, ' Household'))}"
            NumberOfAdults="{'2'}"
            NumberOfDependants="{if(Person/Dependent) then count(current-group()/Person/Dependent) else if(Person/NumberOfDependents) then sum(current-group()/Person/NumberOfDependents) else '0'}">



        </Household>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

I get

```
<Household UniqueID="b8b0f908b08e-Household"
           Name="Sanchez Household"
           NumberOfAdults="2"
           NumberOfDependants="1"/>
<Household UniqueID="bd8c65a3ad80-Household"
           Name="Bonkers Household"
           NumberOfAdults="2"
           NumberOfDependants="2"/>
```

this way with Saxon 9.8 EE inside of oXygen.

For Saxon 9.8 HE it should be possible to rewrite that as

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="Party" use="Identifier"/>

<xsl:template match="PartySegment">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Party[Person/MaritalStatus/@Status = ('DeFacto', 'Married')]" 
        composite="yes" 
        group-by="Identifier | key('ref', Person/MaritalStatus/RelatedEntityRef)/Identifier">
        <Household UniqueID="{concat(Identifier, '-Household')}" 
            Name="{normalize-space(concat(Person/PersonName/Surname, ' Household'))}"
            NumberOfAdults="{'2'}"
            NumberOfDependants="{if(Person/Dependent) then count(current-group()/Person/Dependent) else if(Person/NumberOfDependents) then sum(current-group()/Person/NumberOfDependents) else '0'}">



        </Household>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

For XSLT 2.0 where we don't have composite keys we would need to make sure to construct a single key with both components:

```
<xsl:template match="PartySegment">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Party[Person/MaritalStatus/@Status = ('DeFacto', 'Married')]" 
        group-by="string-join((Identifier | key('ref', Person/MaritalStatus/RelatedEntityRef)/Identifier), '|')">
        <Household UniqueID="{concat(Identifier, '-Household')}" 
            Name="{normalize-space(concat(Person/PersonName/Surname, ' Household'))}"
            NumberOfAdults="{'2'}"
            NumberOfDependants="{if(Person/Dependent) then count(current-group()/Person/Dependent) else if(Person/NumberOfDependents) then sum(current-group()/Person/NumberOfDependents) else '0'}">



        </Household>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. I was thinking that the solution needs to be a unique key for the grouping and now i know that this has a name (composite key).